# Why do I get integer values when I try to NSLog an iPad's orientation?

Tags: xcode, ipad, integer, orientation

Just wondering why I get integer values when I try to log an iPad's orientation. Is there a resource that tells me what each value means?  I have gotten anything from a 1 to an 8.  I only thought there were 4 possible orientations so I'm confused.

Comment: are you talking about UIInterfaceOrientation or some other set of values?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the 8 different values considering the documentation shows

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

You can log this right before you log the orientation and see which it is.

```
NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait-%d\n\
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown-%d\n\
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft-%d\n\
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight-%d", UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
```

There are convenient ways to test for specific orientations, for example

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the user interface is currently presented in a landscape orientation.

#define UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) \
   ((orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || \
   (orientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```